# How to Order by ID with MySql (ID 1-20)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

if i order my sql data by id and the ids are 1 - 20 i get an result like this:

```
id ; val
1 ; 1
10 ; 1
11 ; 1
12 ; 1
13 ; 1
2 ; 1
3 ; 1
4 ; 1
```

But 10 is larger than 4... what can i do to make order it right?

```
SELECT ID, SUM((Amount)) AS AmountSum
FROM `testdata`
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

id = int

Comment: What is the exact query you're using? As well, what is the datetype of the *id* column?

Comment: What is the data type of your `id` column?

Comment: Why are you using GROUP BY id?

Comment: This is not a `group by` issue. It is an alphanumeric issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY id ASC;` - providing your id is of a numerical data type

Comment: I down-voted this because not only is your answer synonymous with his example query, but doesn't solve the problem. The default (implied) `order by` direction is already in ascending order, which explains why his example results are already displaying in ascending order. The problem here is alphanumeric sorting vs. numeric sorting.

Comment: At the time of posting this answer his question was not complete. Get all your facts straight before down-voting. The OP did not declare that the `id` field was in fact an integer.

Comment: Mike. I had all of my facts straight. My down-vote and comment was not in regards to his lack of information or your knowledge of the `id` column data type. My down-vote and comment was because you literally suggested he do the same thing he was already doing. Your suggested `ORDER BY id ASC` is exactly the same as his original `ORDER BY ID`, regardless of data type.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that the datatype of ID is some kind of string.  if you change it to an Int you should see the correct (numerical) sort that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the ID field to integer to get a numeric ordering:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Amount) AS AmountSum
FROM testdata
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY CAST(ID AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

This query will be inefficient because it is not able to use an index on the `id` field. To improve efficiency you should consider changing the column in the database to a numeric type instead of a character type.

Comment: This is not an efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Added a note about efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

Your id field is not int but varchar. Change it to int.